# How to install PHP support in eclipse Luna?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the latest eclipse version "Luna".

But I am not able to find PHP support in the "Install New Software"

Can anyone provide me with the software site link for installing php support and symfony/twig plugin for eclipse luna ?

Comment: Note that Luna is currently only a Milestone release and has had less testing that a full release. Many plugins may not have been tested at all with it yet.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.mywebschools.com/add-php-support-to-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1. Click on Help on the top menu.
2. Choose Install New Software
3. Choose the Luna from the available site link
4. Now on the below section, type PHP.
5. That should bring you list of softwares for PHP tools.

> http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest/ *(upadated)*

And for Symfony/twig:

> http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/

Comment: The current version is now 3.2, You find the info here http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt

Answer (score 0):

eclipse -> help-> install new software 
work with drop down select your luna 
then list of tools is given below
select programming tool its list of some program language like c c++ php select php then next 
accept the terms and condition that's all over
eclipse open perspective choose php then work in php code

Comment: Please add some punctuation to your answer.